# Why does the 'for' loop change the type of the sequence value?

Tags: r, date, for-loop, attributes

Why does the 'for' loop appear to convert the item it is extracting from the sequence of "Date" items to numeric in the first example, but does handle it correctly if I make a "list" out of the sequence?

```
> dates <- seq(as.Date('2014-3-9'), as.Date('2014-3-12'), by = '1 day')
> str(dates)
 Date[1:4], format: "2014-03-09" "2014-03-10" "2014-03-11" "2014-03-12"
> # seems to convert "Date" to "numeric" when extracting the item in the loop
> for (i in dates){ 
+     str(i)
+     print(i)
+ }
 num 16138
[1] 16138
 num 16139
[1] 16139
 num 16140
[1] 16140
 num 16141
[1] 16141
> 
> # works fine if I put it in a 'list'
> for (i in as.list(dates)){ 
+     str(i)
+     print(i)
+ }
 Date[1:1], format: "2014-03-09"
[1] "2014-03-09"
 Date[1:1], format: "2014-03-10"
[1] "2014-03-10"
 Date[1:1], format: "2014-03-11"
[1] "2014-03-11"
 Date[1:1], format: "2014-03-12"
[1] "2014-03-12"
> 
>
```

Comment: Good catch @Thomas, Ttat is indeed a duplicate and the answer is right there